# How to detect the one function causing a stack overflow quickly in Visual C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-c++, stack-overflow

I have a huge C++ codebase. On a certain set of data there's a stack overflow. If I run the program under Visual Studio debugger I get a call stack 30 unfamiliar functions deep - one (or more) of those functions created a too big object on stack and this lead to stack exhaustion. I looked at all functions and there's nothing obvious - nothing like

```
char buffer[512 * 1024];
```

I though I could add a variable at the beginning of each of those functions and dump that variable address and recompile and then look at difference between adjacent functions, but that's lots of manual labor.

How do I quickly identify the function that created a too large set of objects on stack and causes a buffer overflow?

Comment: Are you sure it is a single function overflowing the stack, or is it due to some unintended recursion?

Comment: I might be missing something, but isn't it always the function at the top of the stack that causes the overflow?

Comment: @jalf: There's only about 30 functions between `main()` equivalent and overflow point, so I'm sure there's no endless recursion.

Comment: @FredOverflow: obviously that's the proximal cause, but if it's `strlen` then you'd probably want to look for something else rather than concluding, "oh dear, `strlen` uses too much stack" ;-)

Comment: @sharptooth: long time since I've used Visual Studio, and nothing like the latest version, but can you put `esp` in a debug window and then roam around the call stack, looking to see where it changes a lot?

Comment: @FredOverflow: Well, it triggers the overflow, but the reason can be some other function used too much stack before this function has been called.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: This will require me to know the exact point at which each function is called. Since many functions are called multiple times along the program runtime it will be very time consuming - much more that the approach I propose in the question.

Comment: Ah, I thought you'd caught the stack overflow in the debugger, and therefore could debug the call stack at point of failure. Never mind, then.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Yes, I have caught it in debugger, but at that point `esp` is for the latest called function, isn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Code Analysis in Visual C++ which is available in higher editions. A warning ([C6262](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7yhee2f0.aspx)) is generated if function uses stack higher than some limit. You may use `/analyze:stacksize` switch, where `stacksize` is limit you want.

Comment: Nice ! There are definitely some good tools integrated in VC++!

Comment: There's one problem with this thing. It doesn't account for temporary objects. It just ignores them. And (guess what) it was a temporary object that caused a stack overflow in our code.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a stack trace (and you should be able to get one), you might be able to access the addresses of the frames.

The one function causing the issue should lead to a huge leap in the frames pointers.

If there is none, check the stack size, it might simply be much too small.

**EDIT:** How to debug non-obvious issues with VC++ ? (hum... I code on Unix :/)

Elan Rusking made a great talk on investigation in his [2011 GDC presentation](http://assemblyrequired.crashworks.org/gdc-2011-crash-analysis-and-forensic-debugging/) ([PDF](http://crashworks.org/gdc11/elan_ruskin_programming_forensic_debugging.pdf)).

The stack pointer is (on x86) stored in the `ESP` register. If you have a look at the disassembly and check the changes of `ESP`, then you should be able to see which function incremented/decremented it with a large value.

Example on [wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/The_Stack#Push_and_Pop):

```
mov eax, DWORD PTR SS:[esp]
add esp, 4
```

This `add esp` is what you want to track. Unless you are using VLAs, the values added/substracted are hardcoded, so easy to check on.

Comment: How do I check frame addresses?

Comment: In debug mode and with frame pointers enabled (default case IIRC) check EBP. See here for how it works http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/misc/misc/stack/article.php/c14799

Comment: @sharptooth: good question, probably with the Watch Window (there's lot of things there). Otherwise you can inspect the disassembly and track `esp` changes, I've added some references / code to my answer.

Comment: +1 / Note: EBP can be checked with a watch expression (just add `EBP` to the watch window)

Comment: @Martin: Yes (and ESP too), however you can compile without frame pointers ( ~ `-fomit-frame-pointer` on gcc) and then EBP is just another register so not so interesting :)

Comment: @Matthieu: From what I know about omitting frame pointers and debuggers, I'd say one should just *not* try to debug something that has this option set :-)

Comment: @Martin: unfortunately, when you get a crash dump, you don't have much choice :/

Answer (score 2):

A thread that exceeds its stack allocation will raise an exception. This exception can be trapped with the `__try` and `__except` keywords in Microsoft Visual C++. You can wrap your functions inside this try-except block to see if they cause the stack overflow.

Take a look here: [How to trap stack overflow in a Visual C++ application](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315937)